# which operator is used to iterate through array element

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

As shown in the following code, the observables i have will mapped using the operator .map() then i want to use .filter opertor. The .map() operator will 
return an Array, this array contains some elements. how can I pass element by element to the .filter() operator.
beacsue the .filter() operator in the below code receives the entire object Array, then i cant do filtering operation on each single element.

please let me know which operator should i use between .map and ,filter so that .filter operator receives elements of the array instead of the whole object.

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
Observable<String> animalsObservable = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    animalsObservable = Observable.just("Ant", "Bee", "Cat", "Dog", "Fox");
    getAnimalsObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Function<List<String>, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object apply(@NonNull List<String> strings) throws Exception {
                    List tempList = new ArrayList();
                    for (String string : strings) {
                        if (string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
                            tempList.add(string);
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "tempList: " + tempList);
                    String [] str = new String[tempList.size()];
                    tempList.toArray(str);
                    return str;
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<Object>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .subscribe((Consumer<? super Object>) getAnimalsObserver());
}

private Observable<List<String>> getAnimalsObservable() {
    return Observable.fromArray(Arrays.asList(
            new String[]{
                    "Ant", "Ape",
                    "Bat", "Bee", "Bear", "Butterfly",
                    "Cat", "Crab", "Cod",
                    "Dog", "Dove",
                    "Fox", "Frog"
            }
    ));
}

private Observer<? super List<String>> getAnimalsObserver() {
    return new Observer<List<String>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSubscribe->d: " + d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<String> s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNext->s: " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onError->e: " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete");
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Neither `.map()` nor `.filter()` is an operator.

Answer (score 1):

[map operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) transform `Observable<Something>` into `Observable<SomethingElse>`

In your code, map transform `Observable<List<String>>` into `Observable<String[]>`

if you want to filter String you will need `Observable<String>` from `Observable<String[]>`

this code should work fine, I used [flatmap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) then [toList](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/to.html) to make your code works:

```
getAnimalsObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(new Function<List<String>, String[]>() { //map to String[]
                @Override
                public String[] apply(@NonNull List<String> strings) throws Exception {
                    List tempList = new ArrayList();
                    for (String string : strings) {
                        if (string.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")) {
                            tempList.add(string);
                        }
                    }
                    //Log.i(TAG, "tempList: " + tempList);
                    String[] str = new String[tempList.size()];
                    tempList.toArray(str);
                    return str;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<String[], ObservableSource<String>>() { //flatmap to String
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<String> apply(String[] strings) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromArray(strings);
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(String s) throws Exception {
                    return true; // filter with a condition
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .subscribe((Consumer<? super Object>) getAnimalsObserver());
```

However, this approach is far better (I'm using java8 lambda and use `Observable<String>` from begining):

```
    Observable.fromArray(new String[]{
            "Ant", "Ape",
            "Bat", "Bee", "Bear", "Butterfly",
            "Cat", "Crab", "Cod",
            "Dog", "Dove",
            "Fox", "Frog"
    })
            //suppose that observable above came from another thread
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().startsWith("b"))
            .toList()
            .subscribe((Consumer<? super Object>) getAnimalsObserver());
```

Comment: That `subscribeOn().observeOn()` makes little sense here unless you place the `filter().collect()` in between them to "offload" the computation. Also there is the `toList()` operator which does exactly what you wrote with `collect()`.

Comment: thank you so much, I will update my answer according to your recommendation

Comment: now when i try to use the same code as yours..i get .filter of type Object not String as follows: .filter(new Predicate<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                        return false;
                    }
                })

Comment: don't use Predicate<Object> instead use Predicate<String>

Comment: @maheryhaja i am receiving an error when i use String instead of Object

Comment: did you use exactly:
.filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(String s) throws Exception {
                    return true; // filter with a condition
                }
            })

Comment: @LetsamrIt: replace every occurrence of Object with String then you won't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove second filter and insert a flatMap and inside flatMap do the filtering.

```
getAnimalsObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map(.....)
        .flatMap(i->
                 {return io.reactivex.Observable.fromArray(i)
                    .filter(new Predicate<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(String s) throws Exception {
                           return false;
                        }
                    }).toList().toObservable();
                 })
       .subscribe(getAnimalsObserver())
```

**Flow of the Observables**:

```
[.map->Observable<String[]>] ->
[flatMap->[fromArray->Observable<String>] -> [filter
->toList.observable()]->Observale<List<String>>]
```

Comment: @Letsamrlt: Could you please tell me, if it works in your case?